# SSIS expressions to create Weekly folders

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a weekly folders created manually in my system once in a week where files will be moved here. Now we want to automate this task by using SSIS.

Below are the folder structures for the month of September

**MY16 WE SEP 04 16

MY16 WE SEP 11 16

MY16 WE SEP 18 16

MY16 WE SEP 25 16**

MY means Marketing Year, WE indicates week.

Now we need to create folders for the month of Oct for 2nd, 9th, 16th, 23rd, 30th and for coming months.

MY16 WE OCT 2 16
..
..

how to write expression/function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that considers the date of the current day and check out on the day of the week, then move the day at the end of the week;
 first you need to introduce two variables for day of week (@[User::DayOfWeek]  int32) and month (@[User::VariableMonth] String), **supposing to calculate month and year on the last day of the week**:

@[User::DayOfWeek]

```
DATEPART( "dw",  getdate() ) == 1 ?    6  
 : DATEPART( "dw",  getdate() ) == 2 ?   5  
 : DATEPART( "dw",  getdate() ) == 3 ?   4  
 : DATEPART( "dw",  getdate() ) == 4 ?   3  
 : DATEPART( "dw",  getdate() ) == 5 ?   2  
 : DATEPART( "dw",  getdate() ) == 6 ?   1 
 : 0
```

@[User::VariableMonth]

```
(MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 1 ? "JAN" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 2 ? "FEB" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 3 ? "Mar" : 

  MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 4 ? "APR" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 5 ? "MAY" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 6 ? "JUN" : 

  MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 7 ? "JUL" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 8 ? "AUG" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 9 ? "SEP" : 

  MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 10 ? "OCT" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 11 ? "NOV" : MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )) == 12? "DEC":"")
```

the expression you need:

```
"MY" + RIGHT((DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate()  )),2) + " WE " +  @[User::VariableMonth] + " " +RIGHT(  "0" + (DT_WSTR,2) DAY(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() ) ),2) + " " +  RIGHT((DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate()  )),2)
```

Result with getdate()

```
   MY16 WE OCT 23 16
```

I hope this help. 
*You can also combine all the variables into one, but it is difficult to understand and display.*

Comment: it really helped, but in my expression instead of OCT 23 , i am getting date as Oct 22.  i am not clear about the expression used in @DayOfWeek, as for current day value should be 4, where as expression yields  3 where upon my date value changes to OCT 22 instead of OCT 23.

Comment: There's probably another default notation when the week starts on Sunday, Can you tell me what returns DW calculated on Sunday with your settings? Should be 1.

Comment: Yes it is returing 1

Comment: We could use a work around to change DayOfWeek setting. How you prefer to associate your days? To the following Sunday or to the previous Sunday?

Comment: to the following Sunday

Comment: Try this DayOfWeek: `DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 1 ? 0 : DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 2 ? 6 : DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 3 ? 5 : DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 4 ? 4 : DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 5 ? 3 : DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 6 ? 2 : 1`